# JSF Richfaces fileUpload testing by HtmlUnit

Tags: jsf, richfaces, htmlunit

My question is how can i test Richfaces FileUpload by HtmlUnit.

My **html page** code is like:

```html
<div class="uploadFile">
    Upload File:
    <div id="allForm:upload" class="rf-fu ">
        <div class="rf-fu-hdr">
            <span class="rf-fu-btns-lft">
            <span class="rf-fu-btn-add">
            <span class="rf-fu-btn-cnt-add" style="background-position: 2px 2px; padding: 3px 5px 3px 21px;">
            <span class="rf-fu-inp-cntr">
            <input class="rf-fu-inp" type="file">
            </span> Add...
            </span>
            </span>
            <span class="rf-fu-btn-upl">
            </span>
            <span class="rf-fu-btns-rgh">
            </div>
            <div class="rf-fu-lst" style="height: 0px"></div>
            <div class="rf-fu-cntr-hdn">
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

My **java htmlunit test code** is like:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "browsers")
public void testFileUpload(BrowserVersion browserVersion) throws IOException {
    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) doLogin(browserVersion);
    HtmlFileInput fileUpload = page.getElementByName("rf-fu-inp");
    assertNotNull(fileUpload);
    fileUpload.setData(fileForUpload(FILEPATH).toByteArray());
}
```

In this case, I get the following exception:

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[*] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[rf-fu-inp]
```

My main problem is that I have not a id on the input element else I have the chance to make something like this.

```
 HtmlFileInput fileUpload = (HtmlFileInput) page.getElementById("rf-fu-inp");
```

Comment: There aren't any other getters than "byName" and "byId"?

Comment: I searched for richfaces fileupload setters (name and id) but they are not for the <input tag. In JAVA htmlUnit  getter "byName" i received the following exception: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[*] attributeName=[name] 
and for getter "byId": java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :true
Actual   :false

Comment: That does not answer the question.

Comment: ok yes sorry you are right. i am looking again and it seems that this two getters are the only getters to take elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```html
 //UplaodFile
        HtmlFileInput htmlFileInput = null;
        DomNodeList<DomElement> inputs = page.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (DomElement domElement : inputs) {
            if (domElement.getAttribute("class").equals("rf-fu-inp") &&
                    domElement.getAttribute("type").equals("file")) {
                htmlFileInput = (HtmlFileInput) domElement;
                htmlFileInput.setValueAttribute(System.getProperty("basedir") + FILEPATHCURRENTXML);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
page.getByXPath("//*[@class='rf-fu-inp']")
```

which means: find by XPath, all tag names '*' from root element "//" with an attribute "class" of value "rf-fu-inp".

Please read more in [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) and the HtmlUnit [API](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#getByXPath(java.lang.String))

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?